# Booth Algorithm in string

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I tried solving this [problem](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/BEADS/) in SPOJ using [Booth Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation) in O(n) time, but it failed though it worked for all test cases I tried.
Then I did in Brute force way in O(n^2) time, it worked. I have attached the code for both the cases, tell me where I went wrong or is Booth algo a correct approach for this problem?

Isnt the problem, finding the minimum rotation for Lexicographically smallest string

For first approach, Booth Algorithm : http://ideone.com/J5gl5
For second approach, Brute Force : http://ideone.com/ofTeA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your algorithm gives the wrong answer for string "ABAED", for example.

Your algorithm returns 7 (even though this is longer than the string!).

The correct answer is 0.

(Note this bug may also be present in wherever you found a description of the algorithm! If you look at the history/discussion for the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation) there are a lot of edits fixing bugs - both claiming to fix bugs in the original paper, and to fix bugs in bugfix...)

It seems to work a lot better if you replace:

```
if( lst[i] < lst[ans+i+1] )
```

with

```
if( lst[j] < lst[ans+i+1] )
```

Comment: Anyway, the current version in the wikipedia article returns 7 for that input too. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation&oldid=487873057 works at least for that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, any volunteers for raising this as a bug on the discussion page on wikipedia?

Comment: @peter: It worked, but can you explain what is the need for that change and in what cases `if( lst[i] < lst[ans+i+1] )` will fail??

Comment: @sabari As I understand the algorithm, `i` is the length of a lexicographically minimal prefix starting at index `k` which is identical to the substring from index `j - i` to `j - 1`. Of course you want to compare the letter after the common substring to check which is lexicographically smaller, the letter at index `i` is completely unrelated.

Comment: @sabari: I believe it is just a bug in the current wikipedia implementation and my suggested fix should work in all cases (I made a simple test that ran lots of random strings through the algorithm with the proposed change and validated the results against a brute force checker)

Comment: @DanielFischer and peter: Thanks a lot for the bug fix and explanation!